# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, constructor, this

This is my code:

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
var name = (cookies.get('name'));
var key = (cookies.get('key'));
console.log(key);
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: amber,
    secondary: blue
  },
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  bottomView: {

    width: '25%',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0
  },
});
class Base {
  constructor() {}
}

class Homework extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      topicBox: null,
      payloadBox: null
    };

    this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  async loadTest() {
    try {
      //grab courses
      const response = await fetch('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?access_token=' + key);
      const json = await response.json();
      //coursemax vars will eventually be user defined
      var coursemax = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

      if (json.courses != null) {
        for (var course = 0; course < json.courses.length && course < 9; course++) {
          //grab course info
          var coursework = await fetch('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/' + json.courses[course].id + '/courseWork?access_token=' + key);
          var coursejson = await coursework.json();
          console.log(coursejson);
          var assignment = "";
          for (var assignmentnum in coursejson.courseWork) {
            if (assignmentnum <= coursemax[course] - 1) {
              //add in assignment
              assignment += "<p>" + coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].title + "</p>";
              //"Due: "+coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].dueDate.month+"/"+coursejson.courseWork[assignmentnum].dueDate.day
            }
          }
          //making ids to render
          document.getElementById('class' + (course + 1) + 'info').innerHTML = assignment;
          document.getElementById('class' + (course + 1)).innerHTML = json.courses[course].name + '</b>' + ':' + '<br/>';;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}
var app = new Homework();
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
app.loadTest();

function publish() {
  console.log(this.state.topicBox, this.state.payloadBox);
  const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');
  const item = {
    title: this.state.topicBox,
    user: this.state.payloadBox
  }
  itemsRef.push(item).set("name");
  this.setState({
    topicBox: '',
    payloadBox: ''
  });

}

const LoginPage = () =>
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static" id='title'>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography type="title" color='inherit'>
              MVHS Homework App
            </Typography>
            <div id='avatar' color='inherit'><Avatar>{name[0]}</Avatar></div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Paper id='calendar'>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class1"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class1info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class2"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class2info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class3"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class3info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class4"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class4info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class5"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class5info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class6"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class6info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell><p id = "class7"></p></TableCell>
                <TableCell><p id = "class7info"></p></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="topicBox" 
        placeholder="Name" 
        value={ this.state.topicBox }
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
      />
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="payloadBox" 
        placeholder="Details"
        value={ this.state.payloadBox } 
        onChange={ this.handleChange } 
      />
      <Button variant="raised" color="secondary" style = {theme.bottomView} onClick={ this.publish }>
        Secondary
      </Button>
      </div>

    </MuiThemeProvider>



export default LoginPage
```

In the code above, there is an error on:

> this.publish = this.publish.bind(this);
>   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

And the Error is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of
>   undefined

Why is this happening?

***EDIT:*** The error I believe is the only issue with the code right now. Feel free to tell me if anymore errors. :)

Comment: Why are you mixing `const` and `var`? If you're using ES6+, best to never use `var`, hoisting and function scope can easily cause confusion

Comment: I am new to this please be more specific. Is this relevant to the issue?

Comment: `publish` is not a property or function of the `Base` class (or initialized in the `Homework` constructor), so you can't `bind` it

Comment: How do I fix. Please post an answer.

Comment: Can u help pls @CertainPerformance

Comment: For a start, make `publish` a property of `Base`s or put it in the `Homework` constructor, I guess, if that's what you need

Comment: Can you please post specific code. I just started learning JS today.

Comment: You haven't said what you're trying to do in the big code block you posted - try figuring out objects and Classes first. (in short, start from Chapter 1, not Chapter 40)

Comment: No I need this done today and I just need to fix the error pls help. You talked about how to fix it so can u please show the code to do so..

Comment: @CertainPerformance please HELP ME! what do you mean by "put it in the Homework constructor'

Comment: Re. `const`, `var`, and `let`: `var` has unexpected scoping. If you have `if (true) { var foo = 1; } console.log(foo)` will print '1' because `var` variables are scoped to the enclosing function, not block. That what Certain means by 'hoisting'. `let` has the more expected scope, and replacing `var` with `let` would have the expected results of `foo` being undefined outside the if-block. When you don't need to change the variable reference or simple value `const` is even better. It scopes like `var`, but protects from accidental chages to references or simple values.

Comment: Please stop pinging me, look up a tutorial on how classes work

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your handleChange method.

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }
```

...

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

ps:
Please be more especific, the errors references to what?

```
 Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

Comment: where do I put the handleChange(event)

Comment: inside the class, like @CertainPerformance says, chapter 1, not 40. take a look: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

you have `import React from 'react'` in your code?